# How to change the tz in records stored by the usage of django-auditlog in django admin panel

Tags: django, audit-logging, django-auditlog

I am using the **django-auditlog** library to store audit logs concerning some of my models.

I noticed that despite the fact that I have defined the time zone in `settings.py` all the models containing fields of type `DateTimeField` are stored in UTC time in my admin panel in Log entries section.

Here is my `settings.py` part concerning time and time zone configurations :

```
USE_L10N = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Athens'
USE_TZ = True
```

What to do in order the log audit records to be in timezone defined by me and not in UTC?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution I was searching for.

In `settings.py` I had to declare the below:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Athens'
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = False
class TimezoneMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
    def __call__(self, request):
        timezone.activate(pytz.timezone('Europe/Athens'))
        return self.get_response(request)
```