# AuditLog rows have a wrong timezone in timestamp column

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-auditlog

I installed AuditLog according to the [documentation](https://django-auditlog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#manually-logging-changes). Changes are being logged just fine and are save to DB with the right timezone (UTC+6). But when I browse them in admin panel, they come in UTC+0 timezone. Any common ways to fix this?

[How to change the tz in records stored by the usage of django-auditlog in django admin panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65286544/how-to-change-the-tz-in-records-stored-by-the-usage-of-django-auditlog-in-django)

This did not help.